# cURLpp linker error

Tags: c++, macos, linker-errors, curlpp

Hi I get `linker command failed with exit code 1` after install cURLpp throw homebrew using this command: [`brew install curlpp`](http://brewformulas.org/Curlpp).

How do I fix this? I'm on a Mac. I looked this up, but the answers are incomplete.

**Edit:** Here's the [code](http://pasteall.org/818409/cpp), [makefile](http://pasteall.org/818412) and [full error](http://pasteall.org/818407/cpp).

Comment: is there anything else in the logs?

Comment: Gotta be more than than that. There's not enough information in that error to do much more than quit programming in disgust and move to a farming commune.

Comment: Hahaha, sorry about that. I added more information.